How to manage duplicate resource in gradle build task
I use Gradle to build my Spring Boot project.
And the project use external libraries.
If A Project and B.jar has duplicate files.
Which file is used first?
A Project
---resource/templates/test.html
B jar
---resource/templates/test.html
When I tested it worked like below
If A project has test.html

using A Project's test.html

If A project has not test.html

using B.jar's test.html

It works as i want but I want to clearly how gradle handles with duplication resource prioirty.
Is there any document about this?
Thanks
